# sqlalchemy query ignoring some rows

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a sqlalchemy query that goes basically like this

```
for row in session.query(Message).order_by(Message.ts):
    print(row)
```

This should print both of these rows:

```
             ts             |    uts     | user  |    message
----------------------------+------------+-------|---------------
 2016-01-20 06:07:38.905547 | 1453270059 | user1 |  REDACTED
 2016-01-20 06:07:39.029675 | 1453270059 | user2 |  REDACTED_UNIQUE
```

but it is only printing one of them. I can filter by user1 or user2 and get each row individually, but I can't get both of the rows. I am trying to iterate over all rows (6.5 million) and process each one. But ones with similar timestamps like this one keep getting skipped.

Here is the Message class:

```
class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'log'
    __init__ = Base.__init__

    ts = Column(DateTime)
    uts = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    user = Column(String(24))
    message = Column(String(512))
```

Comment: I think you should complete the question with Message definition / metadata. Thanks.

Comment: @J_Zar what kind of metadata? I could give the Message schema if that's what you mean

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html... This is the mapping you are using since I can see the Message class in your query.

Comment: What happens if you use: `session.query(Message).all().order_by(Message.ts)`

Comment: @IanAuld .all() returns a list which doesn't have an order_by method so it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the Message class was what was wrong. Somehow the primary_key got moved from ts to uts. sqlalchemy wasn't choking on my incorrect primary key but was assuming that there were no duplicates in the uts column (which was a problem because the uts column isn't unique). Moving it back to ts (which is a unique column) fixed the problem. The Message class should be:

```
class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'log'
    __init__ = Base.__init__

    ts = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)
    uts = Column(BigInteger)
    user = Column(String(24))
    message = Column(String(512))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to add a call to `all()`

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html

all()

Return the results represented by this Query as a list.
This results in an execution of the underlying query.